# adding two addthis buttons on runtime with different URLs

Tags: jquery, addthis

I am adding two addthis divs in my application I want both of them to have different URLs. and I want to set their URLs on the runtime in jquery how can I do that? I've two divs which I will use to share two different links,  I am trying following code:

```
<div id="div1" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"  >
    <a class="addthis_button_gmail addthis1"  addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email addthis1" addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_delicious addthis1" addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_yahoomail addthis1"  addthis:title="My title" ></a>                                      
    <a class="addthis_button_favorites addthis1"  addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact addthis1"  addthis:title="My title" ></a>                                    
</div>
```

and I've my second div which I want to use for a different link,

```
<div id="div2" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style" style="display: none;" >
    <a id="shareChartfb" class="addthis_button_facebook addthis2" addthis:title="My title"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter addthis2" addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share addthis2" addthis:title="My title" g:plusone:count="false"></a>                             
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share addthis2" addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_tumblr addthis2" addthis:title="My title" ></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact addthis2"  addthis:title="My title" ></a>                                    
</div>
```

Actually the two links are generated on runtime in jQuery, link1 and link2, I am trying following code:

```
var link1= //generated on runtime
var link2= //generated on runtime
addthis.update('share', 'url', link1);
                addthis.url = link1;
                addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");
```

and for link2 I use the same code:

```
addthis.update('share', 'url', link2);
                addthis.url = link2;
                addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");
```

so it is setting div1 and div2 both to link2, I want to know some method or somthing which sets div1 to link1 and div2 to link2.

Comment: Have you tired anything? Please post your code atleast HTML so we can have some idea on what you are actaully trying to do.

Comment: @bipen I've edited my post with my code please have a look

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1:

Have you tried adding `addthis:url="http://example.com/foo"` into the attributes for the parent `div`?

`http://support.addthis.com/customer/en/portal/articles/125634-setting-the-url-title-to-share`

If that url isn't populated yet by the time `addthis_widget.js` loads on your page, you might have issues with option 1. Sometimes you can get around that with..

### Option 2:

option 1 and then call `addthis.layers()` after.

### Option 3:

Leave the class and addthis:url attributes off the div until you have both of the urls, then add the attributes and call `addthis.layers()`.

You might want to wrap you `addthis.layers()` call in something like this to make sure you call it only after it's available:

```
(function() {
    var at_interval = setInterval(function () {
        if(window.addthis) {
            clearInterval(at_interval);
            addthis.layers();
        }
    },1000)
}());
```